# problems in sign apk ionic android in cmd

Tags: android, ionic-framework, apk

I am trying to sign an android application (certificate / keystore.) with this

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

but when appearing enter password .no He lets me write anything, so I press enter and he tells me the password is invalid

```
Enter the password for the keystore:
The keystore password is too short, it must be at least 6 characters

Enter the password for the keystore:
Retype the new password:
Do not match. Try again

Enter the password for the keystore:
The keystore password is too short, it must be at least 6 characters
Too many failures; try again later
```

When I put C:\ ... keytool `-keypasswd` in the cmd 
say:

```
-scripts key tool error: java.lang.Exception: The keystore file does not exist: C: \ Users \ .keystore
```

what I do ?

Comment: mi jdk is jdk1.8.0_73

Comment: Are you actually trying to enter a password with 6 characters?

Comment: i was resolve for myself thanks so much